# How to store image file in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a form and wanted to store all the information in PHPMyAdmin. I managed to store the other information but not the image file. It has nothing under the image column in PHPMyAdmin even though it states submitted when I submit the form.

form2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<h1>Found Items Handover</h1>

    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2>1. Details of Handover Personnel </h2>
        </div>


<form action="insert2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="row input-container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="styled-input">
                    <input type="text" name="name"required />
                    <label>Staff Name</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <div class="styled-input" style="float:right;">
                    <input type="text" name="staffno" required />
                    <label>Staff Number</label>
                </div>
            </div> <br>
                <div>
                  <label>Attachment:</label><input type='file' name='file'><br>
                </div>
            </div>


<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

inser2.php

```
<?php

    $con= mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','satsform1');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not Connected To Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'satsform1'))
    {
        echo 'Database Not Selected';
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $staffno = $_POST['staffno'];







    $sql = "INSERT INTO handover (name,staffno) 
    VALUES ('$name','$staffno')";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
  $target_dir = "upload/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  // Select file type
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Valid file extensions
  $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

  // Check extension
  if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

     // Insert record
     $query = "insert into images(name) values('".$name."')";
     mysqli_query($con,$query);

     // Upload file
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);

  }

}

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo 'Not Submitted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Submitted';
    }


?>
```

I expect the URL of the image to be stored in PHPMyAdmin when I submit the form.

Comment: You can’t store in phpmyadmin.  It is a name of a web based MySQL browser.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?  Any error message?

Comment: Btw learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: It is a bit hard to debug your code without knowing your DB structure. First of all, please try to check `in_array($imageFileType, $extensions_arr)` condition and make sure that it is working correctly, then please check `insert into images(name) ...` query, please put some dummy data to this query and make sure that everything is working fine there.

Answer (score 0):

please insert following code in insert2.php file with your respective variable and file names.

```
<?php

$con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','join');

if(!$con)
{
echo 'Not Connected To Server';
}

if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'join'))
{
echo 'Database Not Selected';
}
$target_dir = "uploads/";
echo "<br>";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "<br>";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$staffno = $_POST['staffno'];


// get details of the uploaded file
$fileTmpPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));
$allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png','jpeg');
if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions)) {



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) { 
echo "File uploaded successfully!"; 

$query = "INSERT INTO user (image) 
VALUES ('$target_file')";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
echo 'Not Submitted';
}
else
{
echo 'Submitted';
}

} else{ 
echo "Sorry, file not uploaded, please try again!"; 
} 

}





?>
```

Comment: Never ever suggest anyone use concatenated SQL strings. Always use parameters/prepared statements